# $\int \frac{e^x}{\sqrt{2e^x+e^{2x}}}dx$ integration

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis

$\int \frac{e^x}{\sqrt{2e^x+e^{2x}}}dx$

I have no idea how to do it:( What is more I don't know how to start it... Any ideas? I will be pretty grateful. I tried some tricks but no one works.

Comment: $t=e^t$ could be a good idea?

Comment: In fact, the best idea. Just $t=e^x+1$.

Answer (score 4):

Let $u = e^x$, and then you will have $du = e^x dx$, and thus you will obtain

$$\int \frac{du}{\sqrt{u^2 + 2u}} $$

Evaluate this integral by completing the square in the denominator.

Comment: got it! now it looks much better